How can I match this expression using CTRE?
I have the following regex:
(?<weekday>\w{3}),\s+(?<day>\d{1,2})\s+(?<month>\w{3})\s+(?<year>\d{4})\s+(?<hours>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2})\s+(?<timezone_offset>[+\-]\d{4})(?:\s+\((?<timezone_name>\w+)\))?

The goal is to match the following date:
Fri, 2 Aug 2024 18:02:15 -0000 (UTC)
The reason I am using regex is because it could be any of the following (basically anything in roughly that format):
Fri, 2 Aug 2024 18:02:15 -0000 (UTC)
Fri, 2 Aug 2024 18:02:15 +0000 (UTC)
Fri, 2 Aug 2024 18:02:15 0000 (UTC)
Fri, 2 Aug 2024   18:02:15   -0000 (UTC)
Fri, 2 Aug 2024 18:02:15 0000 (UTC)
Fri, 2   Aug   2024 18:02:15 -0000 (UTC)
Fri,                 2 Aug 2024 18:02:15 -0000
...

Using regex101.com I can match them all just fine under the PCRE setting. Unfortunately, with the following ctre code the first match contains the whole string:
static constexpr ctll::fixed_string ctll_pattern = { R"((?<weekday>\w{3}),\s+(?<day>\d{1,2})\s+(?<month>\w{3})\s+(?<year>\d{4})\s+(?<hours>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2})\s+(?<timezone_offset>[+\-]\d{4})(?:\s+\((?<timezone_name>\w+)\))?)" };
static constexpr ctll::fixed_string ctll_weekday = "weekday";
static constexpr ctll::fixed_string ctll_day = "day";
static constexpr ctll::fixed_string ctll_month = "month";
static constexpr ctll::fixed_string ctll_year = "year";
static constexpr ctll::fixed_string ctll_hours = "hours";
static constexpr ctll::fixed_string ctll_minutes = "minutes";
static constexpr ctll::fixed_string ctll_seconds = "seconds";
static constexpr ctll::fixed_string ctll_timezone_offset = "timezone_offset";
static constexpr ctll::fixed_string ctll_timezone_name = "timezone_name";

std::string s_weekday, s_month, s_timezone_name;
int day = 0, year = 0, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0, timezone_offset = 0;

const auto all_matches = ctre::multiline_search_all<ctll_pattern>("Fri, 2 Aug 2024 18:02:15 -0000 (UTC)");
for (const auto& match : all_matches)
{
        std::cout << match.to_string() << "\n";
}

Is there some particular detail about CTRE which is stopping this from being matched? Unfortunately, I am rather new to regex so this is a quite hard to debug.
Bonus: any way to make this compile faster? Visual Studio 2022 MSVC 19.40 builds this is about 15 seconds in debug mode and ~30 min in release mode. This is unrelated though, but I figured someone may have some kind of knowledge here.
Compile Explorer

Each match will contain all capture groups. In your example, there will be only a single match. Capture groups can be extracted like this:
const auto all_matches = ctre::multiline_search_all<ctll_pattern>("Fri, 2 Aug 2024 18:02:15 -0000 (UTC)");
for (const auto& match : all_matches)
{
    std::cout << match.get<ctll_weekday>() << std::endl
        << match.get<ctll_day>() << std::endl
        << match.get<ctll_month>() << std::endl;
    // Or use numbered access.
    match.get<0>(); // capture 0 is the whole match
    match.get<1>(); // weekday
    match.get<2>(); // day
    // ...
}

See: https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions/blob/main/README.md#using-captures

Perfect, thank you! I did some matching before, but all the patterns had | between them which I believe makes them different matches whereas here they are all the same.

Why do you use std::endl when just '\n' would suffice?

Several reasons: 1) I think std::endl is more explicit. 2) You want a std::endl at the end anyway to flush. 3) Mixing std::endl and '\n' is inconsistent. Furthermore, I think it would be very rare for a few extra flush calls to be a significant performance bottleneck.
